# Multi-input Convolutional Neural Network for Images Classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am beginner in deep learning and I want to create a multi-input Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) model in Keras for **Images Classification**.

I am working to create a CNN model that takes **two images** and gives **one** output which is the **class of the two images**.

I have two datasets: type1 and type2, and each dataset contains **the same  classes**, but **the number of images in each class in the dataset type1 is higher than the number of images in each class in the dataset type2.** 
The model should take one image from Type1 dataset and one image from Type2 dataset and then classify these images to **one class** (ClassA or ClassB or------).

The following is the structure of the datasets.

```
Type1 dataset
|Train
              |ClassA
                             |image1
                             |image2
                             |image3
                             |image4
                            -----
              |ClassB
                             |image1
                             |image2
                             |image3
                             |image4
                            -----
              |ClassC
                             |image1
                             |image2
                             |image3
                             |image4
                            -----
              |ClassD
                             |image1
                             |image2
                             |image3
                             |image4
                            -----
       ----------------
|Validate
            -----------
|Test
           --------------

Type2 dataset
|Train
              |ClassA
                             |image1
                             |image2
                            -----
              |ClassB
                             |image1
                             |image2
                            -----
              |ClassC
                             |image1
                             |image2
                            -----
              |ClassD
                             |image1
                             |image2
                            -----
       ----------------
|Validate
            -----------
|Test
           --------------
```

The model is very similar to the model in this images, but it has more layers before flatten layer.

[image: Multi-input]

I created a custom generator that inputs two images (from type 1 and 2), and each image from type1 be paired with every images from type2 as long as these images belong to the **same class (label)**.

The problem is when executing `fit_generator` I get infinite loop as the following:

```
  Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.

    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes.
    Found *** images belonging to 100 classes. ......
.................................................................
```

Here is my custom generator code:

```
input_imgen = ImageDataGenerator( 
                                  rotation_range=10,
                                  shear_range=0.2,
                                  zoom_range=0.1,
                                  width_shift_range=0.1,
                                  height_shift_range=0.1
                                  )



test_imgen = ImageDataGenerator()



def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, batch_size, img_height,img_width):


    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
    while True:
      X2i = genX2.next() 
      Type1 = []
      Type2 = []
      image1 = []
      image2 = []

      while True:
        X1i = genX1.next() 
        for i in range(len(X2i[1])): #Type2
          for j in range(len(X1i[1])): #Type1
            if all(X2i[1][i]) == all(X1i[1][j]): # have same label
              image1.append(X1i[0][j]) # add image
              image1.append(X1i[1][j]) # add label
              image2.append(X2i[0][i]) # add image
              image2.append(X2i[1][i]) # add label
      Type1.append(image1)
      Type2.append(image2)
      yield [Type1 [0], Type2 [0]], Type2 [1]  #Yield both images and their mutual label


inputgenerator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=input_imgen,
                                           dir1=train_iris_data,
                                           dir2=train_face_data,
                                           batch_size=32,
                                           img_height=224,
                                           img_width=224)       

validgenerator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=test_imgen,
                                          dir1=valid_iris_data,
                                          dir2=valid_face_data,
                                          batch_size=32,
                                          img_height=224,
                                          img_width=224) 

testgenerator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=test_imgen,
                                          dir1=test_face_data,
                                          dir2=test_face_data,
                                          batch_size=32,
                                          img_height=224,
                                          img_width=224)


    # compile the model
    multi_model.compile(
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),
            metrics=['accuracy']
        )


# train the model and save the history
history = multi_model.fit_generator(
inputgenerator,
steps_per_epoch=len(train_data) // batch_size,
epochs=10,
verbose=1,
validation_data=validgenerator,
validation_steps=len(valid_data) // batch_size,
use_multiprocessing=True,
shuffle=False
)
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem and create the custom generator??

Comment: Since you know the structure and filenames for each of your datasets, you can create a list of filename tuples which are of the same class but from your different types and then use a generator to read the images from these filenames and yield the images and the label?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I apply this suggestion, I need to duplicate the images in the datasets and I have a lot of images. Do you think duplicating the number of images better than creating a custom `fit_generator`?

Comment: if you have lot of images, then maybe you could think about sampling your data so that you can feed a sufficient number of them. It may not be necessary to use every combination of these images. The main problem that I see with your current approach is it would consume a lot of memory to nest generators within generators and then save image data that you get from each generator. Generators are efficient because you use smaller amounts of memory as and when required at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MultipleInputGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, dir_train_01, dir_train_02, batch_size):
        # Keras generator
        self.generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15, 
                                            width_shift_range=0.2,
                                            height_shift_range=0.2,
                                            shear_range=0.2,
                                            zoom_range=0.2,
                                            horizontal_flip=True, 
                                            fill_mode='nearest')

        # Real time multiple input data augmentation
        self.genX1 = self.generator.flow_from_directory(
            dir_train_01,
            target_size = IMG_SIZE,
            batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
            class_mode  = 'categorical',
            color_mode  = 'rgb',          # convert to rgb
            seed        = SEED 
        )
        self.genX2 = self.generator.flow_from_directory(
            dir_train_02,
            target_size = IMG_SIZE,
            batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
            class_mode  = 'categorical',
            color_mode  = 'rgb',          # convert to rgb
            seed        = SEED 
        )

    def __len__(self):
        """It is mandatory to implement it on Keras Sequence"""
        return self.genX1.__len__()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Getting items from the 2 generators and packing them"""
        X1_batch, Y_batch = self.genX1.__getitem__(index)
        X2_batch, Y_batch = self.genX2.__getitem__(index)

        X_batch = [X1_batch, X2_batch]

        return X_batch, Y_batch
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).